# Next JS 13.4 SSG rendering error during build

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to build a Next JS application but I'm getting some errors. I'm pretty new to Next JS and don't fully understand what's going on here. From my understanding, it's trying to statically generate my pages, except this shouldn't happen since everything should be SSR or CSR. Any tips on how to solve this?

```
- info Generating static pages (0/14)
DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `cookies`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error
    at staticGenerationBailout (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/7326.js:290:21)
    at Object.cookies (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/7326.js:173:62)
    at NextServerComponentAuthStorageAdapter.getCookie (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:203:42)
    at NextServerComponentAuthStorageAdapter.getItem (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:572:28)
    at getItemAsync (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:3813:33)
    at SupabaseAuthClient._recoverAndRefresh (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:2701:69)
    at SupabaseAuthClient._initialize (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:1404:24)
    at /vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:1364:35
    at /vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:2042:36
    at SupabaseAuthClient.lockNoOp [as lock] (/vercel/path0/client/.next/server/chunks/9450.js:1276:18) {
  digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE'
}
```